# Retrieving Text from URL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

Can someone please help me understand why my output is "myContent is equal to (null)" with this code:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://moneyfromapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/codetest.txt"];
NSString *myContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL encoding: NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error: nil];
NSLog(@"myContent is equal to %@", myContent);
```

It seems to work with other URLs... Any idea why not with this URL?

Comment: Don't ignore error parameters, use them to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's those ...'s in the URL

```
http://moneyfromapps.com/wp-conte…/uploads/…/01/codetest.txt"];
```

Also, always check the NSError you get back from the call.  The website might be down.

Comment: Stackoverflow added those in. The URL works: [http://moneyfromapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/codetest.txt](http://moneyfromapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/codetest.txt)

Comment: Using that URL, and your original code works fine for me here.  I'm running Xcode 6.1.1.

Comment: Forgot to mention -- you're not checking the error object.  If the website is down, you'll get the behavior you mentioned, and you need to check the NSError to find that out.

Comment: Strange. I consistently get "myContent is equal to (null)." Thanks, I'll try with NSError.

Comment: Def check the NSError.  You could have some networking problem between your system and the target URL.